# Bluetooth wont start at Raspberry Pi zero 2

Tags: bluetooth

When I run

```
sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service
```

it shows loaded but not started.
`start` command wont work. I have to use `btusb` first.

```
>>> sudo modprobe btusb
>>> sudo systemctl start bluetooth.service
```

Also bluetooth icon won't show in panel and when i click `Bluetooth Manager` it just do nothing.

When I run `sudo bluetoothctl` is shows

```
Waiting to connect to bluetoothd...
```

When I turn bluetooth on by the command above it and try to `scan on` it says

```
No default controller available
```

Bluetooth wont start when I do anything. OS is newly installed and Rasbperry Pi is also relatively new (bluetooth was working fine till now)

UPDATE:

`hciuart` is also do not working. Here is log

```
Subject: A start job for unit hciuart.service has begun execution
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit hciuart.service has begun execution.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 1294.
Mar 03 15:12:14 raspberrypi btuart[1501]: Can't open serial port: No such file or directory
Mar 03 15:12:14 raspberrypi btuart[1501]: Can't initialize device: No such file or directory
Mar 03 15:12:14 raspberrypi sudo[1475]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Mar 03 15:12:14 raspberrypi systemd[1]: hciuart.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
░░ Subject: Unit process exited
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ An ExecStart= process belonging to unit hciuart.service has exited.
░░ 
░░ The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Mar 03 15:12:14 raspberrypi systemd[1]: hciuart.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ The unit hciuart.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 03 15:12:14 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start Configure Bluetooth Modems connected by UART.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit hciuart.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit hciuart.service has finished with a failure.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 1294 and the job result is failed.
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the full output from `systemctl status bluetooth.service`. Were there any errors reported? Does the command `journalctl -f -u bluetooth` show any errors? What OS is newly install? Have you tried running `bluetoothd` in the foreground with logging? `sudo /usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd -nd |& tee ~/bluetoothd.log`